# sum per day on interval dates

Tags: c#, postgresql

i have a table as follow

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-07-31 |
| 6 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-07-31 |
| 2 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-08-05 |
| 3 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-07-31 |
| 2 | 2021-08-06 | 2021-08-12 |

there a way to have somthing like this

| date | 2021-07-30 | 2021-08-1 | 2021-08-2 | 2021-08-3 | 2021-08-4 | 2021-08-5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

the id is the number of rooms and the start and end dates are when rooms are occupied. I' am trying to get the number (sum ) of rooms occupied in each day.

Comment: Sum of what? What is `count`? What result you expect (not a view, but explanation)? What you tried (code example)?

Comment: the id is the number of rooms and the start and end dates are when rooms are occupied. I' am trying to get the number of rooms occupied in each day

Comment: Are the column headers fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with data as (
  select
    generate_series(min("start"), max("start"), '1 day')::date as date
  from your_table)
select d.date, count(t.id)
from
   data d left join your_table t
     on d.date >= t."start" and d.date < t."end"
group by d.date
order by 1
```